# AMR to WAV converter in Java

Tags: java, audio, wav, amr

Is there AMR to WAV , WAV to AMR converter available written Java? I need to do conversion in realtime. Looking for open source, free or paid.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559746/getting-error-while-converting-wav-to-amr-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be to call ffmpeg from within Java.  Sadly, I don't know of a good solution which is java-only, but using ffmpeg allows you to use the wide range of codecs available to this program (which includes AMR support).

Comment: This works for me on Ubuntu 17.10: 
`Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "-c",
     "ffmpeg -i /home/absin/Downloads/1234.amr /home/absin/Downloads/1234.wav" });`
After doing `sudo apt install ffmpeg` ofcourse!