# getting error while converting wav to amr using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, wav, amr

I am using ffmpeg to convert amr to wav and wav to amr.Its successfully converting amr to wav but not viceversa. As ffmpeg is supporting amr encoder decoder, its giving error.

> ffmpeg -i testwav.wav  audio.amr

Error while opening encoder for output stream #0.0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try setting the sample rate and bit rate. 
Amr supports only 8000Hz sample rate and 4.75k, 5.15k, 5.9k, 6.7k, 7.4k, 7.95k, 10.2k or 12.2k bit rates:

```
ffmpeg -i testwav.wav -ar 8000 -ab 12.2k audio.amr
```